# Convert files to DataFrame and then applying a function for multiple DataFrames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have three files well1.las, well2.las, well3.las (".las" is similar to a ".txt") and want to transform them into different DataFrames (8x4) as I will apply some functions on them later.
Inside them there is a string "~A" that I want to exclude and stay just with the logs names ('DEPTH', 'GR', 'NPHI', 'RHOB') as column names.

I already managed to separate the las file to a dataframe, but couldn't do this to all. How can I do that? 
I think it should be better if I could put the dataframes in a list or dict as I will need to do some calculations with their values.

Each las file looks like this:

```
~A  DEPTH      GR           NPHI          RHOB        
   2869.6250   143.5306      0.1205       2.4523       
   2869.7500   143.9227      0.1221       2.4497       
   2869.8750   144.5697      0.1180       2.4564       
   2870.0000   145.3994      0.1128       2.4650      
   2870.1250   146.3611      0.1378       2.4239       
   2870.2500   147.3796      0.1535       2.3981       
   2870.3750   148.4387      0.1288       2.4387       
   2870.5000   149.5223      0.1195       2.4539
```

'''

```
dl = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\laguiar\Desktop\LASfiles")

for filename in dl:
    if filename.endswith('.las'):
        with open(filename) as f:
            for l in f:
                if l.startswith('~A'):
                    logs = l.split()[1:]
                    break
            data = pd.read_csv(f, names=logs, sep='~A', engine='python')

df = data['DEPTH'].str.split(expand = True)
df = df.astype(float)
df.columns = logs
```

'''

Comment: Simply make data an empy list (`data = []`) before your `for` loop, and each iteration append the result of `read_csv` to that list.

Comment: Thanks, @Valentino! Now I can see my dataframes inside the list 'data'

Comment: Hi @Valentino, is there still something open regarding your question? is `sep='~A'` working? It is usually used to overwrite the column-separator, so in case you want to remove it, you might need to apply something different (reading it without change and then rename the columns, or read the file into memory and remove it bevor you pass it to `read_csv` using `StringIO` etc)

Comment: @jottbe No idea. LucasA seems happy with my suggestion, not sure if there is something more he needs.

Comment: Great :-) Why don't you write an answer then?